# How to set package version when installing using openstack disk image builder?

Tags: package-management, openstack

I would like to set a specific package version for some packages when using disk-image-builder to create images for use with OpenStack. In this case a Ubuntu base image is used and apt for installation. The "package-installs.yaml" file configures which packages to install, but there does not seem to be any way to specify an exact version to use during installation. There is no example in the [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/diskimage-builder/elements/package-installs/README.html) (searching the net also fails to provide an answer).

Example content of package-installs.yaml:

```
my-package:
```

Maybe there is some other way to configure the package version to use, that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Set the package equal to the wanted version in the file:

```
my-package=1.0.0:
```

The image builder will pass the setting to apt which will install the requested version.